# Counting duplicates in table and saving the count to a field in the same table

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio.

I have a temporary table (I'll call it temp_orders) I'm prepping for use later on in a process. It has over a hundred fields, but the pertinent ones are the below:

```
primary_key   order_number   order_info
     1            123           blah
     2            234           blah1
     3            234           blah1
     4            234           blah2
```

See how order_number 234 has two identical order_info entries? One of em's gotta go. But I can't outright delete it just yet; I need to **identify** the duplicate rows so that I trace them back to the source from which this temp_orders table was generated.

So I've added a dupe_number integer field to this temporary table. The goal is for dupe_number to 'count' the number of duplicate order_number/order_info combinations in the table and set it to dupe_number:

```
primary_key   order_number   order_info    dupe_number
     1            123           blah            1
     2            234           blah1           1
     3            234           blah1           2
     4            234           blah2           1
```

This seems really simple, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this. My searching is turning up a bunch of solutions that seem woefully obtuse or that involve cursors. This seems like it should be very simple and I'm just ignorant of an easy solution.

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use either `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK`:

```
SELECT *,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY order_number, order_info 
                              ORDER BY id)
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```